Image Directory Failing to Open Unless label_mode=None
My image directory fails to open unless the label_mode argument of image_dataset_from_directory is None.
I've tried switching the type to 'int', 'categorical' and 'binary' to no avail. I've also tried making a wrapper for the class and then switching the attribute later (which in hindsight, was never going to work), but that didn't work either. I need to somehow keep it off None because I later evaluate the accuracy of the generator and model.evaluate() can't handle the None value. Here is my code thus far:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers, preprocessing, Sequential
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
import glob

class CustomImageDataset:
    def __init__(self, directory, image_size, batch_size, label_mode):
        self.dataset = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
            directory,
            image_size=image_size,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            label_mode=label_mode
        )
        self.label_mode = label_mode

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.dataset)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset)

    def map(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.dataset.map(*args, **kwargs)

    def batch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.dataset.batch(*args, **kwargs)

    def prefetch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.dataset.prefetch(*args, **kwargs)


SIZE = 8
batch_size = 64

train_generator = preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    r'C:\Users\{}\Downloads\archive (1)\noncloud_train',    
    image_size=(SIZE, SIZE),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    label_mode=None
)

validation_generator = preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    r'C:\Users\{}\Downloads\archive (1)\noncloud_test',
    image_size=(SIZE, SIZE),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    label_mode=None
)

anomaly_generator = CustomImageDataset(
    r'C:\Users\{}\Downloads\archive (1)\cloud',
    image_size=(SIZE, SIZE),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    label_mode=None
)



rescaling_layer = layers.Rescaling(1./255)

def change_inputs(images):
  x = tensorflow.image.resize(rescaling_layer(images),[SIZE, SIZE], method=tensorflow.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
  return x, x


# Apply preprocessing to datasets
train_dataset = train_generator.map(change_inputs)
validation_dataset = validation_generator.map(change_inputs)
anomaly_dataset = anomaly_generator.map(change_inputs)

test = anomaly_generator.label_mode
def check_none_in_dataset(dataset):
    for batch in dataset:
        images, labels = batch
        if images is None or labels is None:
            print("Found None in dataset")
            return True
    print("No None values in dataset")
    return False

# Check validation dataset
print("Checking validation dataset for None values:")
c = check_none_in_dataset(validation_dataset)
print(c)

def print_labels_from_dataset(dataset, num_batches=1):
    for images, labels in dataset.take(num_batches):
        print("Labels (should be the same as images):")
        print(labels.numpy())  # Print the labels to check if they are the expected values (not None)s
        print(labels.numpy() == images.numpy())

print("Validation Dataset Labels:")
bat = print_labels_from_dataset(validation_dataset)

print("Anomaly Dataset Labels:")
cow = print_labels_from_dataset(anomaly_dataset)


model = Sequential()
# Encoder
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')) 
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))


# Deconder
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))


model.add(layers.Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    steps_per_epoch = 1500 // batch_size,
    epochs = 1000,
    validation_data = validation_dataset,
    validation_steps = 225 // batch_size,
    shuffle = True
)

# Examine the recon. error between val data and anomaly images
validation_error = model.evaluate(validation_generator)
anomaly_error = model.evaluate(anomaly_generator)


Ensure that your main directory contains subfolders equal to the number of
classes, organize your data accordingly. Then, use the
keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory function to load your image data
directly from this directory structure.Let me know if you are still facing the
issues.
